# Is it advisable to hand in a thesis by visiting my supervisor's house?

Tags: research-process, thesis, paper-submission

I have to hand in the thesis to my supervisor, but I could neither find him in the faculty nor contact him, but I know his house.

Is it advisable to hand in a thesis by visiting my supervisor's house?

Comment: Did you consider leaving it in a pidgin hole for your professor? Or with his/her secretary?

Comment: I think this is a personal, rather than academic question.  If this person has actually been supervising you, by now you should have some sense of their attitudes towards privacy.  If in doubt, I would say no.  If it were my personal advisor, I would say yes.

Comment: My answer is no, not only because of his privacy; but because of the fact that he is your adviser not your neighbor to meet him in home. Further more, he should feel responsible for his student and if he is on a long leave; he should previously inform his students. My advice to you is to call him or send him text message, or email and try to contact him by the university office; if you don't find him, leave a message in his office and give your thesis to his secretary. Every connection should be made inside the university. If you don't succeed these ways, you did your work. Don't be upset.

Comment: The pink elephant in the room — why is the OP having to "hunt" their advisor down to hand off a thesis?

Comment: Because he refused to give his supervisees his contact information. And such questions exist because some members view questions from a Western-perspective.

Comment: @HifaMo: most users have a Western perspective. My observation has been that on this site you will mainly get answers specific to US academic culture, *unless you ask otherwise*, with a few from Europe thrown in for variety. If you want answers specific to the academic culture anywhere other than the US, then you at least have to give a clue where that is :-) Although I'd guess that in any culture, if someone won't give you his phone number it's probably *not* because he wants you to come to his house instead. I may be wrong.

Comment: @Jessop: My idea is that if one has no means of contacting a person, they are compelled to seek his house.

Comment: "Because he refused to give his supervisees his contact information."  Are you saying that your supervisor does not have an email account that you have previously used to contact him?  If the answer is really **no**, then please add more identifying information, including geographic information.  In all academic departments I am familiar with, faculty are required to have an active email account through which they receive important (and unimportant) information regularly.  If the advisor is not answering his emails or says "Don't contact me via email" you need to let us know about that.

Comment: @Clark: That's exactly what I meant. The professor said to us, his supervisees, "You don't need my email; I prefer that you hand me hard copies." Upon asking for his phone number, he said, "Why do you need it," meaning do not insist. Patriotism prevents me from mentioning the geographic location, sorry. Maybe, because we are undergraduates.

Comment: @HifaMo: You should edit that information into your question.  In all the academic contexts I'm familiar with, not giving any email address to your students would be rather unreasonable behavior. "Patriotism prevents me from mentioning the geographic location, sorry." I don't understand what you could mean by this.

Comment: If you do not provide information critical to the answer to your question then (i) I myself am not so interested in answering it; others will be, but (ii) if you leave out key information, the answers that you get may or may not be applicable in a way that could be hard for you to evaluate.  In order for you to confidently judge the applicability of the answers, you would have to have a good understanding both local and global academic culture...which seems to be more knowledge than would be necessary for you to know what to do in your particular situation.

Comment: To follow up on Pete Clark's comment: In the academic contexts I'm familiar with, the university and department _publishes_ email addresses of all faculty, and the university uses that email address for all but the absolutely most formal communication.  Even [Don Knuth](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/email.html) has an administrative email address.

Comment: @SteveJessop: "if someone won't give you his phone number it's probably not because he wants you to come to his house instead" - I see a significant difference between "coming to someone's house" (implying entering, or at least talking at the door; certainly privacy-related) and sending a letter (not that different from a phone call, rather less direct).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: maybe that's what the questioner means, although given how shifty this supervisor seems to be, getting a receipt might be in order ;-) Anyway if you are just going to put it in the mailbox of the house then I'd expect an academic to have a mailing address at the faculty that would do as well.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: "patriotism". I've encountered something like this before on Workplace. Occasionally people don't want to state their country because they don't want a bunch of foreigners concluding or saying, "the standard practice in your country is appalling". Of course in this case it means that the questioner can't get an opinion on whether this even *is* standard practice, and there's a standard response to it, or if this supervisor has gone off the rails and the response is to go up the hierarchy.

Comment: Going to his house without prior notice (agreeing some specific time to meet by email or phone) is too close to harassment, from my perspective. Besides, I guess he is not at his house at all times, e.g. my "supervisor" is out this week (with all family -nobody in the house) due to vacations, going to his house would be a waste of time, greater or lesser depending on my patience waiting at his door. Meetings should be agreed before at least for this reason.

Comment: "Why do you need it," "I need it because I need it to arrange a appointment time with you Prof, you certainly don't want me crashing into your house without prior notice, I presume?"

Comment: Most of the professors in my university have regular office hours, where they set aside the time to be in their office for any students that have any queries. This is usually published in the university website or the professors would tell it to the class at the beginning of the semester.

Comment: @HifaMo: Does your professor has a secretary? Even if you definitely want to hand over your thesis in person,  you can ask the secretary to arrange an appointment in the professor's office.

Comment: I have to say that this appears to be a rather strange university if the only means of contacting your supervisor is to go to their office (not even having a departmental administration office).  One wonders how such a university would deal with a formal complaint from a student about poor or inadequate supervision!  Or for that matter, with a student claiming to have submitted a thesis that was later lost.  IMHO, the fact that your supervisor has discouraged you from contacting him in any other way, I would suggest that even posting the thesis through the letter box would be a bad idea.

Comment: Assuming that by *handing in* you mean the “final submission” of the thesis, I am surprised that you directly give your thesis to your supervisor and not to some examination office (which then distributes it to your supervisor and potential other reviewers). Even if this is not the default way at your university, such an office may still exist.

Comment: I find it unusual you have to hand in the thesis to your supervisor. The practise I know is to hand in the thesis with a department or university office (or even the jaintor when submitting at 23:59 on the last day), who will make an official note that and when it was submitted, so you have a proof of this fact for later reference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I wouldn't find it okay if someone would come to my house because of that. Work and personal life should be separate and it would be inappropriate to visit the supervisor there.

Does he not have an office? If nobody can tell you where to find him, then you should call him or write an email and ask for an appointment.

Comment: The supervisor should also have a mailbox and people at the office who know how to contact the supervisor.  Leave a copy at the office as well as a message about where the copy is.  Keep a backup copy in case the supervisor wants you to drop by the house anyway, (but let them suggest it: it is less appropriate for you to offer anything other than "how shall I get it to you").

Comment: You are over-generalizing. In my institute, professors call students to their home occasionally.

Comment: @user13107: Visiting someone's home because you've been invited by them is much different than dropping in on someone's home unannounced.  The idea that it is potentially invasive to make an unannounced visit to someone's home is not particular to academia.

Comment: In my opinion, vocabulary such as "coming to my house" and "visiting someone's home" is blurring the issue. Unless the supervisor's house actually doesn't have a mailbox, we are talking about dropping something into someone's mailbox (= sending a letter) here, aren't we?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper If this is the official submission of a thesis, the timely receipt of which will decide about the student's career, it would be careless to just drop it into a mailbox, wouldn't it?

Comment: @StephanLehmke: I am not sure what is careless about leaving a document in the mailbox of someone's private home, which is about as direct as the submission can become short of ringing and handing it over in person (and actually even more direct than sending it via mail or having someone place it in the supervisor's office). That said, the OP is talking about their *supervisor*, who - unless specified otherwise - is not necessarily the professor grading the thesis. Likewise, the OP does not specify whether this is about the final submission of a thesis (which, depending on the place, ...

Comment: ... may involve a lot more than handing over the document, namely some registration of the submission process with the database of the institution, for example), so all we know for now is that the OP wants to "informally" hand over a copy of their thesis to their supervisor, possibly for proofreading or advice or any other supervising activity related to a thesis.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ah, Ok. I missed that detail (non final submission). Quite confusing situation.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: To be clear, I agree if this is indeed about the timely recept of a final submission. However, at least in the institutions I am familiar with, thesis supervisors generally would not want to burden themselves with checking, and possibly formally certifying in any way, the timely receipt of any submissions, as centralized student databases are much more suitable for tasks such as keeping track of who started what on what date and who has to finish what by what date. Least of all, they would keep track in their head, or any other means readily available in their private home.

Answer (score 11):

As a faculty member, I value my privacy. Home is home and work is work. Unless I suggest this myself, I would be displeased by a student coming to my house unannounced.

Comment: This is exactly right. I would be incredibly ticked off by a student showing up unannounced at my home, unless either I invited the student (unlikely) or it's an absolute emergency (which I hope is even more unlikely).

Comment: That said, we don't know how long the supervisor's uncontactability has lasted, or how hard the questioner has tried. If he really is so flakey that he isn't visiting the faculty or taking phone calls or checking email, and hasn't told colleagues where he is, for a protracted period, then the questioner is entitled to be displeased already ;-) And on a sombre note, *someone* should go to his house eventually, albeit not the questioner. He might be dead.

Comment: @Steve Chances are then that they won't be at home but in Aruba.

Comment: @RoboKaren: the road trip movie about a student who needs to find his unexpectedly turned-on-tuned-in-dropped-out professor to hand in an assignment before the end of spring break, practically writes itself.

Comment: I assume you will still let people in emergency enter house, even if it's unannounced.

Comment: Sure, but emergency is if someone's physical being is in risk, not if I haven't responded to their email.

Comment: I should mention that undergraduates in particular don't seem to understand "emergency." For them, emergencies seem to include band practice, death of their roommate's great aunt, and watching the world cup. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Following on from a comment by the OP that this supervisor has refused to give his supervisees his personal contact details, I think it's important to say very strongly that **no, in this case it is entirely inappropriate to go to the supervisor's house**.

To even ask it is creepy and weird. If a student actually did this, after I'd refused to give out my personal contact details, I'd be talking to the university administration office; and, depending on their advice and whether or not this had happened before with this student, the police might get involved too. Based on previous experiences, when a student with this sort of serious boundary problem starts creating these sorts of issues, it's important to act decisively and quickly to close things down before they escalate into really serious problems.

**So no, don't go round to your supervisor's house, given that they've already refused to give you their personal contact details. To do so would be creepy and weird.**

Ask the department administrator how you should hand in your thesis to your supervisor: they will either take it on their behalf, or point you at a suitable location to leave it, or provide other guidance.

Comment: Questioner specifically states they don't have the supervisor's email address. I think the supervisor is weird, and possibly negligent of their teaching duties. So I certainly agree with going to department administration, the supervisor is causing students problems, and the department might want to put a stop to it.

Answer (score 2):

I have myself handed in a thesis by visiting a professor's house. But I had contacted him beforehand.

You need to answer -

- Is it really urgent to hand in thesis now?

If the answer is `no`, don't bother with going to house.

Comment: Give it to the department secretary and ask them to time-stamp the cover. Now it's no longer your responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned previously in comments, this answer really depends on the culture of where in the world you are. Within my country, South Africa, I am positive that none of my professors would mind in the slightest if I tracked him down at his home for any query at all. I'd say he would invite me in for coffee while we discussed the issue at hand.

Of course there are exceptions to any rule. There are probably some professors in my institution that would indeed take offence. It could also depend to some small degree on the professor's specific attitude towards the student in question.

I'm talking about an environment where the amount of students any single professor would supervise is small enough that he would know each student personally at least to some degree.

To recap, in my institution I would and have tracked professors down at their homes if I have any queries, even if the reason is not considered particularly urgent.

Comment: As another South African, I can say that if I had showed up an my supervisor's house she would *not* have been happy to see me. *However*, she always made it clear how to get hold of her -- when she would be in her office, which days she didn't check email, etc. -- and would respond to emails or notes left in her pigeon hole promptly.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know your advisor is at home? What if he is on vacation? What if he is out of country?

The purpose to hand in your thesis is to let him read it and review it? right? If he is not home, how do you know he will get your thesis and read/review it?

You need to find his whereabout first. Then contact him and ask him how and where to deliver your thesis. If he tells you to hand in the thesis to his house, do so. If he wants to get it at his office, do so. It's your responsibility to make sure he gets the thesis and read it.