# Is it common to put a quote from interviews in the epigraph page of a thesis as long as research ethics are not violated?

Tags: citations, thesis

I want to put something that one of my participants said in the epigraph page of my thesis, but I have seen researchers mostly quoting authors.

Is it common to put a quote from interviews in the epigraph page of a thesis as long as research ethics are not violated?

Comment: What did the "participants" do? What is the question here? Are you wondering if you are *allowed* to put the quote as an epigraph (ask the person who said it!), or are you wondering if it would make a *good* epigraph (you be the judge)?

Comment: I voted to close, as the question currently is very unclear (see also @Moriarty's questions).

Comment: What did your supervisor say? What do your university's guidelines say?

Comment: @Energy: Comparing with http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24340/is-it-advisable-to-hand-in-a-thesis-by-visiting-my-supervisors-house, in this case I think we can deduce that the supervisor did not have much to say, unfortunately

Comment: @Clark: You're a genius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not common to use quotes from interviews as epigraphs in theses. However, that doesn't mean that you *cannot* do so. So long as the quote contributes materially to your purposes in terms of highlighting it as an epigraph, then it should be fine.